# Create custom Regressor in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I would like to use a custom Regressor with `sklearn` `GridSearchCV`. The spirit of it is analogous to creating a custom Classifier - as shown in this blog:

http://danielhnyk.cz/creating-your-own-estimator-scikit-learn/

Here is a condensed/edited portion of the code from the blog - showing some of the required methods to override.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin

class MyCustomClassifier(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):  
    """An example of classifier"""

    def __init__(self, intValue=0, stringParam="defaultValue", otherParam=None):
        """
        Called when initializing the classifier
        """
        self.intValue = intValue
        self.stringParam = stringParam

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.treshold_ = (sum(X)/len(X)) + self.intValue  # mean + intValue

        return self

    def _meaning(self, x):
        # returns True/False according to fitted classifier
        # notice underscore on the beginning
        return( True if x >= self.treshold_ else False )

    def predict(self, X, y=None):
         ..
```

The things that would be *same* between Regressor and Classifier would likely be the `__init__, fit, predict` methods: I can probably piece that much together. But what about equivalents to `__meaning` ? Or other subtle considerations for a `Regressor` that might not be obvious/clear?

Here is a skeleton I am starting with:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
class MyCustomRegressor(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, regressorMethod):
      self.regressorMethod = regressorMethod

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
      self.regressorMethod(X,y)
      return self
```

It is my understanding that the `score` method will be used by GridSearchCv ..?

Comment: Regarding your last question, the `score` method will be used when you call `.score` on the estimator. For example, in the basic [linear regression model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score), the `.score` method returns "Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction"

Comment: Only thing important for GridSearchCV is `__init__` (for the parameters), `get_params()`, `set_params()` (for parameter assignment for tuning, but these two functions will be inherited from `BaseEstimator`), `fit()`, `predict()` (for obvious reasons), and a `score()` (its only necessary if you are not using the `scoring` param of GridSearchCV.

Comment: `_meaning()` is for internal use only, as denoted by leading `underscore()`. You may use that to do some internal processing on the data or use any other name or multiple internal functions. It should not affect the working of GridSearchCV. GridSearchCV will clone your estimator for each combination of parameters, so unless you declare some class level attributes etc in the implemented functions, nothing extra ordinary should happen. Other than that, I am not pretty clear as to what you want. Can you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: And if you are creating a custom regressor, you should inherit [`RegressorMixin`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.RegressorMixin.html) instead of `ClassifierMixin`, which will have the `score()` method already defined as R-squared value.

Comment: Sure thx  - I just fixed the `ClassifierMixin` -> `RegressorMixin`

Comment: So is this problem solved now?

Comment: I have been under the gun and not had cycles to address yet - even the few required here. Will update in a couple of days.  Feel free to put a question and i'd upvote and then likely award at that time.